# Disable Refresh Token in Keycloak

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-page-application, keycloak, openid-connect

We have an Angular SPA that is authorized by OIDC using the Implicit Flow. We use Keycloak as our authorization server. The Access Token has a short lifespan and is refreshed regularly via a hidden iframe.

After reading that the Authorization Code Flow + PKCE is the new recommended way to authorize SPA's, we decided to switch flows.
Everything works fine, but Keycloak does give us a Refresh Token (along with Access and ID-Token) every time we call the Token-Endpoint.
As there is no secure way to store the Refresh Token, we want to continue using the hidden iframe method for refreshing the access token.

Is there a way to disable refresh tokens in Keycloak?
Or are we missing something? Is it OK to store Refresh Tokens in a SPA?

Comment: did you find out?

Comment: I did not find out yet. We are still using a hidden iframe. I will definitely update this question as soon as i resolved this issue as some people seem to be interested in this. According to this [post](https://auth0.com/blog/securing-single-page-applications-with-refresh-token-rotation/) refresh tokens in SPA are fine as long as "Refresh Token Rotation" is used. I did not find such a feature in Keycloak.

Comment: Did you try to decrease refresh_token lifespan. For example -  to 1 minute?

Comment: I believe that is possible in version 13.0.0. https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-17202?jql=project%20%3D%20KEYCLOAK%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D%2013.0.0%20AND%20text%20~%20%22refresh%22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More recent versions of Keycloak have implemented this feature at the client level under the "OpenID Connect Compatibility Modes" section.

I've verified with version 14.x.

Answer (score 0):

As see from Keycloak's source code it still does not provide a way to disable issuing of refresh token during authentication code flow. Unfortunately you should keep going to use implicit grant flow since refresh token stored on the client side is a big flaw.